# Show that $\iint_R \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}\,dx\,dy$ does not exist over $R=[0,1]\times[0,1]$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Show that the double integral
>   $$\iint_R \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \, dx \, dy$$ does not exist over $R=[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

**My attempt:**

I took $x+y=u$ and $x-y=v$

The jacobian I got is = $\frac{-1}{2}$

The limits according to me should be $u=0$ to $2$ and $v=-1$ to $1$.

The final integration I get is $$\int_{v=-1}^{1}\int_{u=0}^{2} \frac{-v}{2u^3} \, du \, dv$$

But upon integration and putting the limits I get a value of $0\times\infty$ form. Does this prove that the integral does not exist?

PS: I have made an edit to the intergrand. It was earlier $\frac {x-y}{(x+y)^2}$. I have changed it to $\frac {x-y}{(x+y)^3}$. I am extremely sorry to everyone who invested their precious time and effort in the question. There was a typing error in my book.

Comment: This integral must be defined as a multivariable limit.  Like most "nice" multivar limits that don't exist, a good way to show it is to pick a path to the point where you can easily show that it blows up.  Maybe try this here, along a straight-line path to the origin, like $y=-x$.

Comment: Wait, that's a poor choice because it's outside the domain.  But, you get the idea.

Comment: Note that $$x=\frac12(u+v)\qquad y=\frac12(u-v)$$ hence the domain of integration is $$0<\frac12(u+v)<1\qquad 0<\frac12(u-v)<1$$ which is equivalent to $$|v|<u<2-|v|\qquad |v|<1$$ and certainly not the domain you considered.

Comment: it's not clear what you mean by "does not exist". Are you saying this function is not in $L^1$? Please make this clear.

Comment: I don't know what $L^1$ means. By "does not exist", I interpreted that the function is not integrable in the given region $R$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\int\int_R \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^2} \ dx \ dy&=\int\int_R \frac{x}{(x+y)^2} \ dx \ dy-\int\int_R \frac{y}{(x+y)^2} \ dx \ dy\\&=\int\int_R \frac{x}{(x+y)^2} \ dx \ dy-\int\int_R \frac{x}{(y+x)^2} \ dy \ dx\\&=\int\int_R \frac{x}{(x+y)^2} \ dx \ dy-\int\int_R \frac{x}{(x+y)^2} \ dx \ dy\\&=0
\end{align}$$
In the second term in the second line I've just changed the names of the variables from $(x,y)$ to $(y,x)$, and I've used that $R$ is unchanged when I do this substitution

Comment: Separating the integral into the difference in the first line is a sure recipe to "prove" wrong results.

Comment: In order to split the integral like this, you have to assume all integrals actually exist. They do in this case, but replace $\frac{x-y}{x^2+y^2}$ with $\frac{x-y}{(x^2+y^2)^s}$ for some $s\ge3/2$, and they do not exist.

Comment: @Andrei: Please see my edit. I am very sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The integral converges, in fact absolutely. The integrand in absolute value is bounded above by

$$\frac{x+y}{(x+y)^2}= \frac{1}{x+y}.$$

The integral of the last expression can be done directly and you get a nice finite value.

Comment: Please see my edit. I am very sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$, then $x=\frac{u+v}2$ and $y=\frac{u-v}2$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
&=\frac12\int_0^1\int_{-u}^u\frac{v}{u^2}\,\mathrm{d}v\,\mathrm{d}u
+\frac12\int_1^2\int_{u-2}^{2-u}\frac{v}{u^2}\,\mathrm{d}v\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac12\int_0^1\frac0{u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u
+\frac12\int_1^2\frac0{u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u\\[6pt]
&=0+0\\[12pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$
To show that the order of integration does not matter we can use Fubini and show that the integral of the absolute value converges:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{|x-y|}{(x+y)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
&=\frac12\int_0^1\int_{-u}^u\frac{|v|}{u^2}\,\mathrm{d}v\,\mathrm{d}u
+\frac12\int_1^2\int_{u-2}^{2-u}\frac{|v|}{u^2}\,\mathrm{d}v\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{u^2}{u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u
+\frac12\int_1^2\frac{(2-u)^2}{u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u\\[6pt]
&=\frac12+\frac32-2\log(2)\\[12pt]
&=2-2\log(2)
\end{align}
$$

---

**After the Change to the Question**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
&=\frac12\int_0^1\int_{-u}^u\frac{v}{u^3}\,\mathrm{d}v\,\mathrm{d}u
+\frac12\int_1^2\int_{u-2}^{2-u}\frac{v}{u^3}\,\mathrm{d}v\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac12\int_0^1\frac0{u^3}\,\mathrm{d}u
+\frac12\int_1^2\frac0{u^3}\,\mathrm{d}u\\[6pt]
&=0+0\\[12pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$
However,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
&=\frac12\int_0^1\int_v^{2-v}\frac{v}{u^3}\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v
+\frac12\int_{-1}^0\int_{-v}^{2+v}\frac{v}{u^3}\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v\\
&=-\frac14\int_0^1v\left(\frac1{(2-v)^2}-\frac1{v^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}v
-\frac14\int_{-1}^0v\left(\frac1{(2+v)^2}-\frac1{v^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}v\end{align}
$$
and both integrals diverge.

However, the Cauchy Principal Value is $0$:
$$
-\frac14\int_0^1\frac{v}{(2-v)^2}\,\mathrm{d}v=\frac{-1+\log(2)}4\quad\text{and}\quad-\frac14\int_{-1}^0\frac{v}{(2+v)^2}\,\mathrm{d}v=\frac{1-\log(2)}4
$$
and
$$
\text{PV}\frac14\int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm{d}v}v=0
$$
The integral, as presented, is
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
&=\int_0^1\int_y^{1+y}\frac{x-2y}{x^3}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_0^1\left[-\frac1x+\frac{y}{x^2}\right]_y^{1+y}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_0^1\left[\frac1y-\frac1{1+y}+\frac{y}{(1+y)^2}-\frac{y}{y^2}\right]\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{-1}{(1+y)^2}\,\mathrm{d}y\\[3pt]
&=-\frac12
\end{align}
$$

Comment: In your edit, you write $dx\,dy$ instead of $dy\,dx$ when you change the order of integration. But I think the integral is zero and not divergent.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are seeing a change of order with $\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}y$. I change variables to $u$ and $v$, but I don't think I change the order of integration. In any case, the problem was changed from $(x+y)^2$ to $(x+y)^3$ in the denominator and I missed changing that in the $\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$ integrals. I have fixed that. The integral diverges, but the [Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) is $0$.

Comment: The revised integral diverges indeed. But as I see it, you do change the order of integration after you change variables to $u$ and $v$. One gives you the answer zero and the other gives you divergence. Is that correct? And without changing variables, I end up with $\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}\,dx\,dy=-\frac{1}{2}$ (if I change the order I get $+1/2$).

Comment: One integral is rotated one way by the substitution, the other is rotated the other way. It essentially comes to a change in the order of the variables. However, the fact that one diverges, shows that the Lebesgue integral doesn't exist; although, different approaches to the integral (e.g. the Cauchy Principal Value) do converge.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: I get the the same as what you got. I have added the evaluation of the integral "as presented".