# Proving that $\iint\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}\,dx\,dy$ does not exist over $0 \leq x \leq 1 , 0 \leq y \leq 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

To prove that double integral does not exist:

> $$\iint\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^2}\,dx\,dy$$ over region $0 \leq x \leq 1 , 0 \leq y \leq 1$.

I put $x - y = u$ and $x+y = v$ and I got integral as

$$\iint \frac{u}{v^3}\,du\,dv$$

Limits of $u$ are from $2-v \leq u\leq v-2$ and $v$ are from $0$ to $1$. I am not sure about my new limits and how to prove it further.

EDIT : The correct expression is $\iint\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}\,dx\,dy$

Comment: Just to make sure, Waa the question to find whether or not this exists?

Comment: Is it $\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^2}$ or $\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}$? See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2394504/show-that-the-double-integral-int-int-r-fracx-yxy3-dx-dy-does-no?rq=1.

Comment: @Gathdi: If you have $(x+y)^2$ in the denominator, after the change of variables you'll have to have $v^3$, not $v^2$ as you write. Please check the exponent and correct the post if necessary, before we begin to post our answers.

Comment: @Gathdi It still exists, see my edited answer.

Comment: As a Riemann or Lebesgue integral it does not exist. Also iterated integrals are unequal with opposite sign.

Answer (score 9):

There are four interpretations of this question, which explains seemingly conflicting answers.

(1) This does not exist as a Riemann integral.  For a function to be Riemann integrable it must be bounded, but we have

$$\lim_{x \to 0+, y = 0} \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} = \lim_{x \to 0+} \frac{1}{x^2} = +\infty$$

An unbounded function $f:(0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ cannot satisfy the definition of Riemann integrability. For partitions $P$ of the domain into subrectangles, the limit of Riemann sums $S(P,f)$ as the partition norm $\|P\| \to 0$ will fail to exist.

(2) The integrand is also not Lebesgue integrable since it fails to be absolutely integrable.  Using polar coordinates, for any $\delta > 0$, we have

$$\begin{align}\int_{(0,1]^2} \left|\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \right| &= \int_{(0,1]^2} \frac{|x-y|}{(x+y)^3} \\  &\geqslant \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_\delta^1 \frac{r |\cos \theta - \sin \theta|}{r^3(\cos \theta + \sin \theta)^3} r \, dr \, d\theta \\ &= \int_\delta^1 \frac{dr}{r}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{ |\cos \theta - \sin \theta|}{(\cos \theta + \sin \theta)^3} \, d \theta \\ &= -\log \delta \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{ |\cos \theta - \sin \theta|}{(\cos \theta + \sin \theta)^3} \, d \theta  \\ &= -0.5 \log \delta \end{align},$$

and the RHS converges to $+\infty$ as $\delta \to 0+$.

(3) As an iterated integral, by antisymmetry it is clear that

$$\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \, dx\right)\, dy = -1 \cdot \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \, dy\right)\, dx, $$

and depending on the order of integration the value is $\pm \frac{1}{2}$. Inequality of the iterated integrals also implies non-integrability both in the sense of Riemann and Lebesgue, since, otherwise, Fubini’s theorem would be violated.

(4) As an improper integral the principal value obtained by integrating over $S_\delta = [0,1]^2 \setminus \{(x,y): \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \delta, x \geqslant 0, y \geqslant 0\}$ is

$$\lim_{\delta \to 0+} \int_{S_\delta} \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} = 0$$

Comment: Could you please explain why it is clear by antisymmetry that the integrals are different by a factor of -1 .

Comment: @A.R.K: The integrand has the property $f(x,y) = -f(y,x)$. Changing the label “x” to “y” and “y” to “x” in both the integrand and in “dx” and “dy” does not change the value of the iterated integral. Both of these properties together gives the result.

Comment: $$\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \, dx\right)\, dy = \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 \frac{y-x}{(y+x)^3} \, dy\right)\, dx=   \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 (-1)\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \, dy\right)\, dx$$

Answer (score 5):

Given Integral $$ \begin{align} I &= \int^1_0 \int^1_0 \cfrac{x-y}{(x+y)^2} dx dy \\
                                  & = \int^1_0 \int^1_0 \cfrac{x+y-2y}{(x+y)^2} dx dy \\ & = \int^1_0 \int^1_0 \cfrac{1}{(x+y)} dx dy - 2 \int^1_0 \int^1_0 \cfrac{y}{(x+y)^2} dx dy \\ & = \int^1_0 \ln(x+y) \bigg|_0^1 dy + 2 \int^1_0 \cfrac{y}{x+y} \bigg |^1_0 dy  \\ & = \int^1_0\ln (y+1) dy - \int^1_0\ln(y) dy   - 2 \int^1_0 \cfrac{dy}{y+1} \\& = (y+1)(\ln(y+1)-1  )\bigg|_0^1 - y(\ln(y)-1)  \bigg|_0^1 - 2 \ln(y+1) \bigg |^1_0 \end{align}$$

Which is easy to evaluate, and I think the only slight problem would be in evaluating $y \ln(y) $ at $x = 0$, which is just $0$.
I don't see any problem with this.

---

**After changing the question**

Given integral:

$$ \begin{align} I &= \int^1_0 \int^1_0 \cfrac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} dx dy \\
                                  & = \int^1_0 \int^1_0 \cfrac{x+y-2y}{(x+y)^3} dx dy  \\& = \int^1_0 \int^1_0 \cfrac{dx dy}{(x+y)^2} - 2 \int^1_0 \int_0^1 \cfrac{y}{(x+y)^3} dx dy \\& = -\int^1_0  \cfrac{ dy}{(x+y)} \bigg |^1_0 + \cfrac{2}{2} \int^1_0  \cfrac{y}{(x+y)^2} \bigg |^1_0 dy  \\& = - \int^1_0 \bigg( \cfrac{1}{y+1} - \cfrac{1}{y} \bigg) dy + \int^1_0 \bigg( \cfrac{y}{(1+y)^2} - \cfrac{1}{y} \bigg ) dy \\ & = - \int^1_0 \cfrac{dy}{(1+y)^2}  \\& = {- \cfrac{1}{2}}\end{align}$$

But $$ \int^1_0 \int^1_0 \cfrac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} dy dx = \cfrac{1}{2} $$
Then from converse of [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini's_theorem_for_non-measurable_functions) this integral doesn't exists.

Comment: answer would be +1/2 , but I followed the "orders" given by  OP

Comment: The two iterated integrals $\iint \cdots \,dx\,dy$ and $\iint \cdots\,dy\,dx$ exist but are not equal. Hence the double integral does not exist.

Comment: Reference please?

Comment: It follows as a corollary of Fubini's theorem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini's_theorem_for_non-integrable_functions and the answer by @RRL. The (improper) double integral exists iff it converges absolutely, which is not the case here.

Comment: How have you computed answer to be 1/2 in last dydx integral ?

Comment: No, checked on mathematica

Answer (score 0):

This integral evaluates to $0$. Expanding on Ajay's answer, working out those bounds gives exactly $0$.
$$2(\mathrm{ln}(2)-1)+1+1-0-2\mathrm{ln}(2)-0 = 0$$
Solving the integral as attempted in the problem, one gets:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^2\int_{2-v}^{v-2}\frac{u}{v^3}\,du\,dv &= \int_0^2\frac{1}{v^3}\left(\frac{1}{2}u^2\bigg|_{2-v}^{v-2}\right)\\
&= \int_0^2\frac{1}{v^3}0\,dv = 0
\end{align*}